# How to select a string depending on a prefix and a suffix, but not them

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a collection of strings like that (each "space" is a tabulation):

```
29  301 3   31  0       TREZILIDE       Trézilidé
2A  001 1   73  1   (LE)    AFA (Le)    Afa
```

What I want is to transform it into this:

```
29301 Trézilidé
2A001 (Le) Afa
```

- Suppression of the first tabulation
- suppression of the tabulations, numbers and the first uppercase occurrence (and replacement of the whole stuff by a space)
- replacement of the last tabulation by a space

My bigger problems are:

- How to select the first tabulation without selecting the "prefix" and the "suffix"? (like `^(..)\t[0-9]` but without selecting `^(..)` nor `[0-9]`)
- How to select from after the 3 digits to after the tabulation of the uppercase word?

I do that in a text file with the search and replace toolbox of Notepad++

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to select the first tabulation without selecting the "prefix" and the "suffix"?

Optimally this is done using lookahead and lookbehind assertions, but Notepad++ doesn't support those before version 6.0. The next best solution is to just capture them, then backreference them in the replacement string.

Here's how I did it (in answer to your full question):

1. Check **Match case** to do a case-sensitive find
2. Find by regex:

   ```
   ^(..)\t(\d\d\d)[\tA-Z0-9()]+\t(.+)$
   ```

   Replace with:

   ```
   \1\2 \3
   ```

   I end up with this, where `<tab>` represents an actual tabulation:

   ```
   29301 Trézilidé
   2A001 (Le)<tab>Afa
   ```
3. To get rid of that I do an extended find:

   ```
   \t
   ```

   And replace it with the space character, to obtain the final result:

   ```
   29301 Trézilidé
   2A001 (Le) Afa
   ```

Comment: +1 I was running an older version of notepad++ and was wondering why I couldn't use assertions. Thankfully this post was one of the first that came up!

Comment: @Malachi: I haven't been able to come up with a solution to this particular question using assertions. But it's always good to know it finally supports them now :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: It looks like lookbehinds are not supported :( Only forward assertions.

Comment: @Malachi: Interesting. Maybe more complex ones aren't supported. I can match `abc` in `; abc` using `(?<=;\s).*` but not when I use `(?<=;\s*).*`

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I think it could be. I'm no regular expression expert but `(>"(?!\s+)).+((?<!\s+)"<)` This works in eclipse but not in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(..)\t
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

Then

```
\(*[A-Z][A-Z]+\)*
```

Replace with empty string, removes `(LE)` and AFA too.

```
''
```

Then

```
^(.....).*(\t[A-Za-z]+)+$
```

Replacement:

```
\1 \2
```

And finally:

```
\t
```

Replace with a space. Every occurence.

HTW

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me ^^